# Why is render coming out SQueezed together?

Tags: rendering

Hey all do you knoe why this is happening?

Here are my output setting
https://ibb.co/f12ycc9
https://ibb.co/YjxLgrD

and what I mean
https://ibb.co/74FmSvv

Also am interested in how to unsQueeze the image

Comment: Please insert screenshots into your question (use Edit at a bottom of your post), So your links are permanent, This site is knowledge base, so others can learn from you. Thank you to keep this site useful.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed **Aspect** X/Y?

[image]

Comment: Yes? because i wanted a wider aspect ratio, but how can I unsQueeze it? without changing the aspect ratio

Comment: With cursor hovering above value you can read from description it is PIXEL aspect ratio not image aspect. See link posted by Duarte (bellow your title) for more info. But I agree it is confusing to represent this by changing just camera aspect, it should be seen squeezed through camera view, probably. How to make it wider? I'm sure you will discover that :)